# Jquery Bouncing Images Hover

Tags: jquery, image

How to bouncing images using jQuery when we hover the images?

Answer (score 4):

This would be like

```
$('img').bind('mouseenter', function(){
     $(this).effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
});
```

using jQuery UI effects.

Comment: These links were banned for a reason: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Nick: oh wow, I didn't even know that. Well, at least I added a slighty advanced description. But for questions like this, I take the shame for that.

Comment: Taking back my down vote since you have provided an answer. Its better if you can delete that link also.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but if you're using jQueryUI, it has a `bounce` effect.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/G8Ste/

```
$('#myimage').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce',500);
});​
```

You can test the various effects here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: @jAndy - You must be kidding.